# Converting hex strings to byte arrays and back to hex strings in Java

Tags: java, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, serialization

Here is my attempt at converting hex strings to byte arrays and converting byte arrays to hex strings:

***`net.coderodde.util.ByteStringConverter`***

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ByteStringConverter {

    /**
     * Converts the given byte array to its textual hex representation.
     * @param bytes the byte array to stringify.
     * @return the string representing the input byte array.
     */
    public static String convertByteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(2 * bytes.length);

        for (byte b : bytes) {
            stringBuilder.append(convertByteToHexString(b));
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Converts the given hex string to the byte array it represents.
     * @param hexString the hex string to convert.
     * @return the byte array represented by the input hex string.
     */
    public static byte[] convertHexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[hexString.length() / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2) {
            byteArray[i / 2] = convertHexByteStringToByte(
                    hexString.substring(i, i + 2));
        }

        return byteArray;
    }

    /**
     * Converts the input character {@code c} to the nibble it represents. This
     * method assumes that {@code c} is numeric or within range 
     * {@code a, b, c, d, e, f}.
     * @param c the character to convert to a nibble.
     * @return the byte value of the textual representation of a nibble.
     */
    private static byte convertHexCharToNibble(char c) {
        c = Character.toLowerCase(c);

        switch (c) {
            case '0':
                return 0;
            case '1':
                return 1;
            case '2':
                return 2;
            case '3':
                return 3;
            case '4':
                return 4;
            case '5':
                return 5;
            case '6':
                return 6;
            case '7':
                return 7;
            case '8':
                return 8;
            case '9':
                return 9;
            case 'a':
                return 10;
            case 'b':
                return 11;
            case 'c':
                return 12;
            case 'd':
                return 13;
            case 'e':
                return 14;
            case 'f':
                return 15;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a hex digit: " + c);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts the input hex byte string to the byte it represents.
     * @param hexByteString the hex byte string to convert.
     * @return the byte value represented by {@code hexByteString}.
     */
    private static byte convertHexByteStringToByte(String hexByteString) {
        char lo = hexByteString.charAt(1);
        char hi = hexByteString.charAt(0);
        byte lob = convertHexCharToNibble(lo);
        byte hib = convertHexCharToNibble(hi);
        return (byte)((hib << 4) | lob);
    }

    /**
     * Converts the given byte to its textual hex representation.
     * @param b the byte to convert.
     * @return the textual representation of the byte {@code b}.
     */
    private static String convertByteToHexString(byte b) {
        byte lo = (byte)(b & (byte) 0xf);
        byte hi = (byte)((b >>> 4) & (byte) 0xf);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(2);
        appendNibbleToStringBuilder(stringBuilder, hi);
        appendNibbleToStringBuilder(stringBuilder, lo);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Appends the textual representation of {@code nibble} to 
     * {@code stringBuilder}.
     * @param stringBuilder the target string builder.
     * @param nibble the nibble to append.
     */
    private static void appendNibbleToStringBuilder(StringBuilder stringBuilder, 
                                                    byte nibble) {
        switch (nibble) {
            case 0:
                stringBuilder.append('0');
                break;
            case 1:
                stringBuilder.append('1');
                break;
            case 2:
                stringBuilder.append('2');
                break;
            case 3:
                stringBuilder.append('3');
                break;
            case 4:
                stringBuilder.append('4');
                break;
            case 5:
                stringBuilder.append('5');
                break;
            case 6:
                stringBuilder.append('6');
                break;
            case 7:
                stringBuilder.append('7');
                break;
            case 8:
                stringBuilder.append('8');
                break;
            case 9:
                stringBuilder.append('9');
                break;
            case 10:
                stringBuilder.append('a');
                break;
            case 11:
                stringBuilder.append('b');
                break;
            case 12:
                stringBuilder.append('c');
                break;
            case 13:
                stringBuilder.append('d');
                break;
            case 14:
                stringBuilder.append('e');
                break;
            case 15:
                stringBuilder.append('f');
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            String hexString = scanner.next();
            byte[] hexBytes = convertHexStringToByteArray(hexString);
            String newHexString = convertByteArrayToHexString(hexBytes);
            System.out.println(newHexString);
        }
    }
}
```

As always, any critique is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implemented `convertByteArrayToHexString` really inefficiently because you allocate a new string for each byte that is converted.

Also, there's no need for a StringBuilder since a character array suffices. The idiomatic code for converting a byte array to a hex string is:

```
public static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] chars = new char[2 * bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        chars[2 * i] = "0123456789abcdef".charAt((bytes[i] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        chars[2 * i + 1] = "0123456789abcdef".charAt(bytes[i] & 0x0f);
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

I wonder why you chose the inefficient variant over this straightforward code.